# mdx - Filter Date to this week days

Tags: mdx, olap-cube, mondrian

I need help to set a member that filters the [DATE].[DATE].Members to this week days and displays only [this week days] sales values. 
The format of my [DATE] Dimension is dd.mm.yyyy, but I can also use my [TIME] dimension that has [TIME].[YEAR].Members, [TIME].[MONTH].Members and [TIME].[DATE].Members. I use Mondrian.

Any Idea?

The code is:

```
WITH 
MEMBER [This week days] as {...}

SELECT
    {Hierarchize({[Measures].[Sales]})} ON COLUMNS,
    NON EMPTY {Hierarchize({[DATE].[DATE].Members})} ON ROWS
FROM 
    [MyCube]
WHERE [This week days]
```

Result should be like:

```
DATE       |    Sales   |
________________________
14.09.2015 |    245665
________________________
15.09.2015 |    0
________________________
16.09.2015 |    0
________________________
17.09.2015 |    0
________________________
18.09.2015 |    0
________________________
19.09.2015 |    0
________________________
20.09.2015 |    0
________________________
21.09.2015 |    0
________________________
22.09.2015 |    0
```

Comment: did you mark any of your previous questions?

Comment: whytheq - I don't know how to do that. I know you replied some of my question but I don't know hot to mark, maybe you can give me some indication.

Comment: to show appreciation that someone has helped and made an effort for you, you can "up" their answer by +1. If their answer pretty much answer's your question, or even just points you in the direction to help solve the question, then you can hit the "tick" sign and it will turn green: http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/dT8/5e6/dT85e6aqc.png